# Why does this code return an empty array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, permutation

Question: Given a collection of distinct integers, return all possible permutations.

Example: Input: [1,2,3]

Desired output:
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]]

Aren't arrays passed by reference in JavaScript? Why is the result array empty when I return it?

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @return {number[][]}
 */
var permute = function(nums) {
  var result = [];
  helper(nums, result, []);
  return result;
};

var helper = function(nums, result, cur) {
  if (cur.length == nums.length) {
    result.push(cur);
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      cur.push(nums[i]);
      helper(nums, result, cur);
      cur.pop();
    }
  }
}
console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever create a single `cur` array when you call `helper`:

```
helper(nums, result, []);
```

Which you proceed to mutate and recursively pass around in `helper`. There's only one array in memory; by the end, you've `.pop`ped the last item from the array, and every item in the `result` array refers to the same object, the now empty `cur` array.

Instead, clone `cur` inside the loop, so that when/if it gets pushed, you're pushing a *new* array, rather than a reference to the old one which will get reused everywhere:

```
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  const temp = cur;
  cur = [...cur, nums[i]]; // Similar to `.push`, except it creates a new array
  helper(nums, result, cur);
  cur = temp; // Similar to `.pop` - reverts the array to what it was originally
}
```

```js
var permute = function(nums) {
  var result = [];
  helper(nums, result, []);
  return result;
};

var helper = function(nums, result, cur) {
  if (cur.length == nums.length) {
    result.push(cur);
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      const temp = cur;
      cur = [...cur, nums[i]]; // Similar to `.push`, except it creates a new array
      helper(nums, result, cur);
      cur = temp; // Similar to `.pop` - reverts the array to what it was originally
    }
  }
}

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, everything in JavaScript is passed by value. In your function `helper`, a local variable `result` will be created and then assigned the value of the argument upon `helper` call. What you most likely want to do is: `result = helper(nums, result, []);`.

Comment: "Everything in JavaScript is passed by value." Technically this is true.  But the value that is copied and passed for non-primitive arguments is a *reference* to the underlying item.  So the caller and the callee have two distinct references, each pointing to the same value.  In other words, the `result` variable in `helper` is (unless reassigned) a reference to the same item referred to by the reference `result` used in `permute`.